# How to generate custom Auditbeat field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I need to insert a field for each event for the auditbeat data. 
That is each document should contain a field `"enviornment": "production"`

Note: I need a solution not involving Logstash

How can I do this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this using logstash and the mutate filter plugin. Something like this:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "enviornment" => "production" }
    }
}
```

EDIT: without logstash. Since the beats are open source you can edit the beat to mach you specification. But this is clearly a bad solution. Another thing that you can check, is processors. But processors is to keep/drop fields and other tasks. I did not find a processor solution to your case.

For last, you have in the configuration file (yml), one field called fields.
Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the output. Fields can be scalar values, arrays, dictionaries, or any nested combination of these. By default, the fields that you specify here will be grouped under a fields sub-dictionary in the output document. To store the custom fields as top-level fields, set the fields_under_root option to true.

```
fields_under_root: true
fields:
  enviornment: production
  another_field: 1234
```

[more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/configuration-general-options.html#libbeat-configuration-fields)

Comment: any solution without logstash?. Only by using Auditbeat

Comment: i edit my response to match your question. Please check it out @ArunMohan